# foreach DataTable row select unique at second column

Tags: c#, foreach, datatable, datarow

Not really sure how do i write my question..but im having trouble on how to write an UPDATE string for mysql for later use from the DataTable

Data:

```
ID  |  NAME
1   |  SWORD
2   |  SWORD
3   |  SWORD
4   |  SWORD
5   |  HORSE
6   |  SWORD
```

Code:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open("update_itemtype_name.txt", FileMode.Create)))
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
       sw.WriteLine("UPDATE itemtype SET name = '" + row[1] + "' WHERE id >= " + row[0] + " AND id <= " + row[0] + ";");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
UPDATE itemtype SET name = 'SWORD' WHERE id >= 1 AND id <= 1;
UPDATE itemtype SET name = 'SWORD' WHERE id >= 2 AND id <= 2;
UPDATE itemtype SET name = 'SWORD' WHERE id >= 3 AND id <= 3;
UPDATE itemtype SET name = 'SWORD' WHERE id >= 4 AND id <= 4;
UPDATE itemtype SET name = 'HORSE' WHERE id >= 5 AND id <= 5;
UPDATE itemtype SET name = 'SWORD' WHERE id >= 6 AND id <= 6;
```

Expected Result:

```
UPDATE itemtype SET name = 'SWORD' WHERE id >= 1 AND id <= 4;
UPDATE itemtype SET name = 'HORSE' WHERE id >= 5 AND id <= 5;
UPDATE itemtype SET name = 'SWORD' WHERE id >= 6 AND id <= 6;
```

how do i get the expected result?

Comment: Why do you expect this result? your current result is exactly what's expected from your code. Also, what if the table contained different values of `Name` for each row?

Comment: this is why i ask here. im sorry that i am new to this..if the 5th entry id=5 name=HORSE, then it should be okay as "UPDATE itemtype SET name = 'HORSE' WHERE id >= 5 AND id <= 5;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `GroupBy`, but to do that, you first need to get an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` of the data rows, using the `OfType` method extension method. Please also note the `OrderBy` - in order to actually get the correct results in case your data table is not ordered correctly:

```
var rowGroups = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().OrderBy(r => r["id"]).GroupBy(r => r["Name"]);

foreach(var rowGroup in rowGroups)
{
    var strUpdate = "UPDATE itemtype SET name = '"+ 
                     rowGroup.Key +
                     "' WHERE id >= "+ rowGroup.First()["id"].ToString() + 
                     " AND id <= "+ rowGroup.Last()["id"].ToString();
}
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/YEAD51810)

**However**, this does have a flaw, since in the data table nothing is forcing you to keep records with the same `Name` value grouped together by the `Id` value. I mean, if your data table would look like this:

```
1, "SWORD"
2, "SWORD"
3, "SWORD"

4, "KNIFE"
5, "KNIFE"

6, "SWORD"
```

you will get these results:

```
UPDATE itemtype SET name = 'SWORD' WHERE id >= 1 AND id <= 6
UPDATE itemtype SET name = 'KNIFE' WHERE id >= 4 AND id <= 5
```

So you might want to do something else, like using the `IN` operator instead of range checks. Something like this should do the trick (you should consider using a string builder instead of concatenation if you have a lot of rows in your data table):

```
var rowGroups = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().OrderBy(r => r["id"]).GroupBy(r => r["Name"]);

foreach(var rowGroup in rowGroups)
{
    var strUpdate = "UPDATE itemtype SET name = '"+ rowGroup.Key +"' WHERE id IN(";

    foreach(var row in rowGroup)
    {
        strUpdate += row["id"].ToString() +",";
    }
    strUpdate = strUpdate.TrimEnd(',') +")";
}
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/DCS6384)

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. in your demo. if i change the 2nd KNIFE(6) to SWORD, it ignore the KNIFE(5) so the result become "id >=1 and id <=6" instead of "id >= 1 and id <=5"

Comment: and my id is not a continuous number 1->20k as it will break as example 1-5, then 10-12, 14-20 and so on..

Comment: I was actually starting to address that in my answer. Will have a demo soon.